# Wordpress + BBPress - Slow submit topic and message

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I’ve a issue with my bbpress forum.

The save for messages or topic are very very slow.

Do you have idea to optimize that ?
My website : http://wikoandco.com/forum/support

Already tried :

> Disabled all plugin
>   Back to default template

Regards (and sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem in the current version so maybe you coudnt do anything about that. But you can try the following things.

My checklist:
Please note that WordPress requirements/recommendations are on wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Some things to check:

– Have you run all the repair tools of bbpress after import to be sure your structure is optimized ?
– Have you deactivated any not-needed plugin ? Is your theme ready for bbPress ?
– Did you try to run performance tools like the P3 plugin performance profiler to narrow down the possible slow parts ?
– Did gtmetrix.com indicate something ? Or what did you see using the Pingdom Tools ?
– Is it for all people in the world the same ? Check with Sucuri performance.

Plugins:

– Are you using any cache mechanism to improve speed where possible ?
– Plugins like W3 Total Cache, Batcache, WP Super Cache or other ?
– Did you check for CloudFlare or the autoptimize plugin ?

Some further reading: codex.bbpress.org/getting-started/improving-performance/

If it would come to database queries, then check these plugins:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor-bbpress-buddypress-conditionals/

Also note that in the upcoming bbPress v2.6, a lot of focus went on possible performance issues.